# Should I use drupal's graphql module?

Tags: drupal, module, graphql, drupal-modules

I'm building a website with drupal as a CMS and going to integrate Graphql as a middleware. I've seen a lot of examples using the drupal's integrated graphql module, but I feel like it goes against the purpose of having a single decoupled middleware.

I'd like to only make one request from the frontend to graphql to then retrieve data from drupal or any other source. Doesn't the graphql module goes against this philosophy or have I misunderstood something?